# How to transform a dict array with multiple key values into a dict with single key value?

Tags: python

I have the following input data

```
options_d = [{'id': 36, 'label': 'Angular'},
 {'id': 37, 'label': 'Java'},
 {'id': 38, 'label': 'PHP'},
 {'id': 39, 'label': 'Python'},
 {'id': 40, 'label': 'C#'},
 {'id': 41, 'label': 'C'},
 {'id': 42, 'label': '.NET'},
 {'id': 43, 'label': 'Ruby'},
 {'id': 44, 'label': 'Rails'},
 {'id': 45, 'label': 'OS-Linux'},
 {'id': 55, 'label': 'Maschinenbau'},
 {'id': 56, 'label': 'Automotive'},
 {'id': 57, 'label': 'Engineering'}]
```

And I would like to have it transformed into

```
{36: 'Angular',
 37: 'Java',
 38: 'PHP',
 39: 'Python',
 40: 'C#',
 41: 'C',
 42: '.NET',
 43: 'Ruby',
 44: 'Rails',
 45: 'OS-Linux',
 55: 'Maschinenbau',
 56: 'Automotive',
 57: 'Engineering'}
```

What I did so far is

```
skillsmap_person = {}
for option in options_d:
    skillsmap_person[option['id']] = option['label']
```

It works. However, is there a one-line dict assignment solution I can use?

Any ideas?

Comment: Define best. I don't see anything wrong or bad with your code... you can make it slightly more concise with a dict comprehension but...

Comment: @Julien Yes, it's a bit unclear, but I tried to circumvent a strict definition by quoting "best" :) - I was looking or a one-liner :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating `dictionary` with `dict comprehensions` -

```
options_dict = {i['id']:i['label'] for i in options_d}
print(options_dict)
    {36: 'Angular',
     37: 'Java',
     38: 'PHP',
     39: 'Python',
     40: 'C#',
     41: 'C',
     42: '.NET',
     43: 'Ruby',
     44: 'Rails',
     45: 'OS-Linux',
     55: 'Maschinenbau',
     56: 'Automotive',
     57: 'Engineering'}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not doing `dict` with list comprehension:

```
>>> dict([i.values() for i in options_d])
{36: 'Angular', 37: 'Java', 38: 'PHP', 39: 'Python', 40: 'C#', 41: 'C', 42: '.NET', 43: 'Ruby', 44: 'Rails', 45: 'OS-Linux', 55: 'Maschinenbau', 56: 'Automotive', 57: 'Engineering'}
>>>
```

Or for lower versions (when dictionaries are unordered):

```
>>> dict([list(i.values())[::-1] for i in options_d])
{36: 'Angular', 37: 'Java', 38: 'PHP', 39: 'Python', 40: 'C#', 41: 'C', 42: '.NET', 43: 'Ruby', 44: 'Rails', 45: 'OS-Linux', 55: 'Maschinenbau', 56: 'Automotive', 57: 'Engineering'}
>>>
```

It simple iterates through the list of dictionaries, and get's the values of the dictionary, then have an outer `dict(...)` for making it a dictionary, so actually, odd indexed value would be keys, even indexed value would be values.

Comment: Very elegant, a pythonic way :)

Comment: this becomes `{'Angular': 36, 'Java': 37, 'PHP': 38, 'Python': 39, 'C#': 40, 'C': 41, '.NET': 42, 'Ruby': 43, 'Rails': 44, 'OS-Linux': 45, 'Maschinenbau': 55, 'Automotive': 56, 'Engineering': 57}` for me

Comment: @tuergeist Oh, i think because you're on lower versions, so i'll edit mine.

Comment: @U9-Forward correct. It works on 3.6 - but is different on 2.7

Comment: @tuergeist Just do `dict((v,k) for k,v in options_dict.items())` to invert it, where `options_dict` is your initial output. Use `.iteritems()` if you are on `Python 2.`

Comment: @tuergeist Edited mine.

Comment: @cph_sto i think mine is more efficient.

Comment: @I am happy for you.

Comment: U9-Forward I like your solution, but it think @cph_sto  makes clear what happens to the reader (as know know, code is read 1000x more often than written :)

Comment: @tuergeist It's your call Sir :) Thanks by the way.

Comment: @tuergeist I added some more clarification.

Comment: @cph_sto Lol, i would answer the same solution actually, if i was the first poster, lol :-)

Comment: @U9-Forward yes yes, if something has been answered, so it's always a good idea to answer with a different method. But, I learnt this method from you to be honest. Thanks a ton Sir.

Comment: @cph_sto +1 for yours.

Comment: @U9-Forward Atleast I beat you in that for I upvoted yours the moment I saw your answer:) Enjoy your day man!

Comment: @cph_sto Lol, have a nice day too, :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
options_d = [{'id': 36, 'label': 'Angular'},
 {'id': 37, 'label': 'Java'},
 {'id': 38, 'label': 'PHP'},
 {'id': 39, 'label': 'Python'},
 {'id': 40, 'label': 'C#'},
 {'id': 41, 'label': 'C'},
 {'id': 42, 'label': '.NET'},
 {'id': 43, 'label': 'Ruby'},
 {'id': 44, 'label': 'Rails'},
 {'id': 45, 'label': 'OS-Linux'},
 {'id': 55, 'label': 'Maschinenbau'},
 {'id': 56, 'label': 'Automotive'},
 {'id': 57, 'label': 'Engineering'}]

{elem['id'] : elem['label'] for elem in options_d}
```

gets you:

```
{36: 'Angular',
 37: 'Java',
 38: 'PHP',
 39: 'Python',
 40: 'C#',
 41: 'C',
 42: '.NET',
 43: 'Ruby',
 44: 'Rails',
 45: 'OS-Linux',
 55: 'Maschinenbau',
 56: 'Automotive',
 57: 'Engineering'}
```